How to execute a query on a column only when it exists?
I'm adding a new column to my Athena table, and I want to perform my new query on the new column only when it exists, otherwise use the currently implemented query on existing columns, in order to retain the logic in case the code were updated first and my other Athena tables were not updated with the new column.
I want to execute both the check column and the new query in a single SQL string in a single API call, instead of sending another dedicated request just for the check, to avoid potential network and server errors along the way.
My idea of implementing the query:
-- check for column exists
WITH has_column AS (
    SELECT count(*) AS c
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
        AND column_name = 'new_column'
)

-- query
SELECT count(tb.id) AS s,
        check_col.c AS has_col
    FROM "my_table" AS tb,
        "has_column" AS check_col
    WHERE 
        CASE
            has_col
            WHEN 1 THEN (
                new_column = 'value'  -- new logic with new column if exists
            ) ELSE (
                current_column = 'value' -- current logic with existing column
            )
        END

As I ran the query on Athena editor, it always reports COLUMN_NOT_FOUND error on the new column (not yet existed) instead of bypassing the case and going on executing the current logic as I thought.
How can I implement this effectively ?

The potential problem here is that your SQL statement needs to refer to the column in question, whether it exists or not.  If doesn't exist, Athena presumably still would have to compile your SELECT query, and that would fail, since the column is not there.

It is something of anti-pattern/bad design to be now knowing what columns exist in the table.  You should review how you ended up in this situation and maybe try to change it.

What is the format of the underlying data files? If it is JSON, you might want to query the JSON directly since it can handle the concept of data being/not being present, and just return a NULL instead.

@JohnRotenstein Yes, the data files are in JSON format. I've tried casting the selected columns as JSON (CAST(new_column AS JSON) AS new_column) but the error still persists.

It would involve bringing in the entire row as one JSON field (or a text field that you can use with json_extract(), and then references the fields relative to the top-level of the JSON record. So, it's a matter of treating it as a table with one column that you use JSON to reference individual elements. It will take a bit of playing-around to get it to work. See: Extract JSON data from strings - Amazon Athena
